# Old QBOE SDK customer

Tags: quickbooks-online

We have a merchant who has been using our old SDK integration of QBOE for a number of years.  Starting on 09-22-2014 he started receiving errors when doing a SignonAppCertRq query. It looks like it is failing when it tries to generate a response. Is there anyone at Intuit who can look into this? I've sanitized the merchants login, appid and ticket; I can email it to Intuit support if needed.

The QBOE Query

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBO 6.0//EN' 'http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd'><QBXML><SignonMsgsRq><SignonAppCertRq><ClientDateTime>2014-09-22T15:22:06</ClientDateTime><ApplicationLogin>qboe.merchants-website.com</ApplicationLogin><ConnectionTicket>TGT-63-LbBOZNF...</ConnectionTicket><Language>English</Language><AppID>654479...</AppID><AppVer>1</AppVer></SignonAppCertRq></SignonMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

The Response from the Intuit Server

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 15:22:07 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8r ApacheJServ/1.1.2
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close

General error building XML response.
Exception from other package:
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.
```

Comment: If you're looking for someone at Intuit, contact them directly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor support question that is addressed to "someone at Intuit" and therefore should be sent to Intuit support.

Answer (score 1):

The qbXML SDK for QBOE was deprecated about a year ago, and has now been discontinued.

You need to port to the new v3 REST APIs.

Comment: This is the right answer. See: https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/09/05/final-migration-update-quickbooks-online-sdk-to-quickbooks-online-rest-api-v3